# Listing outdated files using SVN commands

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How do I list outdated files using SVN commands?

Comment: what is an 'out of date" file?

Comment: @Mitch I assume he means files in the working copy that have been updated in the repo since the last checkout but @Enosh you should definitely clarify this

Comment: I am getting "file out of date filename" error when I am using svn commit

Answer (score 3):

Before merging allways do

```
   svn update
```

Solve conflicts and than checkin.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN: Select "check for modifications" from the menu, then press the "check repository" button. The "Remote text status" and "Remote property status" columns tell you which files, if any, need to be updated before you can commit them.

Command line: `svn status -u`, look for `*`s in the output.